# Symfony Doctrine error: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: symfony, testing, doctrine

I have an issue that happens when I try to connect to db in test environment of symfony, exactly:

```php
$em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['name' => $name])
```

while running phpunit:

```bash
php bin/phpunit src/Tests/Controller/UserControllerTest.php
```

will receive the following error:

> An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

`DATABASE_URL` in `.env.test.local` is the same as not test for speedy development.

adding here db configuration in docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  database:
    container_name: database
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db-name
      MYSQL_USER: symfony
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: symfony
    ports:
      - '4306:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

I'm running Symfony 4.4 on Docker.

I have found the same issue but for Laravel, where it was fixed but not for Symfony. Also seems like it is more of a Doctrine issue.

Comment: Did you clear your cache for the `test` environment?
Does `bin/console cache:clear --env=test` fix your issue?

Comment: doesn't help. The same error actually happens if I use symfony serve -d and try one of the controller routes

Comment: Are you overriding `DATABASE_URL` or setting `APP_ENV` in your Docker compose-file?

Comment: What's the output of `bin/console debug:container --env=test --env-vars` ?

Comment: output is APP_SECRET and DATABASE_URL, nothing else

Comment: added docker-compose.yml configuration in question

Comment: What's the value of `DATABASE_URL` ? Are you running the `bin/console` commands locally or with `docker compose exec [..]` ?

Comment: value of DATABASE_URL is "mysql://root:secret@database:3306/app-db?serverVersion=8.0" and Im not running bin/console so far, somehow didnt need them for my app

Comment: Why is your port forwarding '4306:3306' ? Shouldn't it be '3306:3306' regarding your connection string ?

Comment: Im not that good at this config, but changing it wouldnt help